# How to add rows to DataTable in realtime when sServerSide is true

Tags: datatables

I have a DataTable with the sServerSide option set to true and so it's getting data from the server as expected. I would like to add new rows dynamically into the table (in realtime using WebSockets) - I need a way to directly modify the data cached from the last AJAX call so that even when I switch page on the table, the newly added realtime rows will still be there when I return to the first page.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

The .ajax call should be modified to cache = false

You have to override `fnServerData` http://datatables.net/ref#fnServerData

```
// POST data to server
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#example').dataTable( {
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "xhr.php",
    "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings ) {
      oSettings.jqXHR = $.ajax( {
        "dataType": 'json',
        "type": "POST",
        "url": sSource,
        "data": aoData,
        "cache": false, //set to false so there is no caching
        "success": fnCallback
      } );
    }
  } );
} );
```

Once you refresh the new data will be there.

Reference: 
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/